# Move cart.php and cart-totals.php to checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce

To reduce the number of redirects on my site, i added the cart page on the same page as the checkout. and used this code to do it:

```
function cart_on_checkout_page_only() {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;
    
    // add woocomerce cart shortcode on checkout page
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');
}

// Cart and Checkout same page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'cart_on_checkout_page_only', 5 );
```

The problem is in the layout specifically, on devices it is too far from the order items as the order total is at the bottom of the page near the checkout button. I got a lot of complaints because people are too lazy to scroll down to see the coupon application in the cart at the bottom of the page

so I made the following modification:

I copied the woocommerce plugin files `woocommerce/template/cart/cat.php and cart-totals.php`

and pasted it into my theme in `themes/mytheme/template/cart/custom-cart.php`

and adapted it in the code above:

```
function cart_on_checkout_page_only() {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

    // add custom cart template on checkout page
    get_template_part('template/cart/custom-cart');
}

// Cart and Checkout same page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'cart_on_checkout_page_only', 5 );
```

my code did the job, but I believe there should be a simpler and more elegant way to make this kind of change. it's possible to make more simpler?

by the way I'm using a child storefront theme.